# Shouldn't information concerning "thanks in advance" or "hi" be added to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

Concerning this portion of the FAQ:

[image]

And concerning this post in ([Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)):

[image]

If everyone (Jeff Atwood, as well as many of the mods on SO, and I assume; Joel) think that there shouldn't be lines such as "Thanks in advance." "Hi", in posts, why is there not some specific statement concerning this on the FAQ? For example, it could be something like:

*Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed.*

*Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page.*

**Also, don't include specific lines such as "Hi", and "Thanks" to your posts, or they will be removed.**

This may be interpreted through tag line, however, I think it would be much more clear if it had specific reference to these kind of tags. For example, this wasn't immediately obvious to me that I shouldn't post things like Hi, or thanks, until I saw it mentioned by mods.

Is there any reason there isn't that level of clarity in the FAQ concerning this?

Comment: @Bart, Apologies, I didn't see that thread in my searching concerning the subject, should I flag my post as a duplicate?

Comment: No need to apologize. This one actually took me some searching. I just knew this post existed. And I guess your question will be closed in due time. Perhaps it might serve as a signpost. You can flag it if you want to.